# Set iOS Simulator custom location from terminal

Tags: ios, terminal, ios-simulator

Is there a way to set a custom location on an iOS simulator via terminal?
I know it is possible to do it via debug > Location > Custom Location

I am looking for some sort of command via terminal for integration testing purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is not currently supported via simctl, but I suggest you file a radar asking for this functionality at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 0):

Thought this is funny people creating location script via AppleScripting for Pokemon [Automating Xcode' Debug > Simulate Location command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38493642/automating-xcode-debug-simulate-location-command)